# Rosh Yeshiva - how?

Tags: rabbis, how-to, employment, yeshiva-school

Can anyone provide sources that delineate the path on how to become a Rosh yeshiva?

Please limit questions to sources (not opinions) based on Torah mekoros, biographies (of Roshei Yeshivas) or other relevant sources that can show how one can become a Rosh Yeshiva whether based on a specific individual Rosh Yeshiva and his path or (preferably) not limited to an individual scenario.

Comment: There won't be one path, as there isn't one kind of rosh yeshiva. The title is used for many sorts of positions, some of which are primarily managerial, others focus on teaching, while others are tremendously focused on teaching.

Comment: It probably makes the most sense to "just" focusing on Torah study, and placing yourself on a trajectory towards teaching others, if that is what you want.

Comment: Talking about a more learned position, lightly managerial but hopefully to the point it reaches the level of lamdus to write sefarim, give piskei dinim, and of course teach students how to think about the Gemara super-analytically for the rest of their lives. Just wondering, any specific sources or primary contacts that shaped your answer?

Comment: I don't see the connection between Pirkei Avot's (IIRC, this is in the 6th chapter? If so, it's not from Avot.) kinyanim list and becoming a Rosh Yeshiva. Many Rashei Yeshiva inherit the job via family, such as the Kamenetzky family - now in 2nd generation. For others, they choose someone "prominent". And, sadly, for a number of others, the only criteria is being a good *schnorer*.

Comment: 1. Yes @DanF, what I was referring to from (Chapter 6 Mishna 5). One can get technical as they are Braisos but I've seen just as much seforim include this perek as exclude it (and no, not talking about different Siddurim who would automatically have it for the minhag to say Avos in summer.) 2. The stretch of a connection is a big factor that led to my question for a more related source as, you're right, this is just general means of acquiring Torah regardless of what one plans to do with the acquired Torah. 3. Quite familiar with the family/schnorer approach, neither a personal option.

Comment: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/ask ?

Comment: Start a yeshiva, that's how. If you want to be a Talmid chacham you learn, and if you want to be a Maggid Shiur In a yeshiva you should focus on the yeshivishe mesechtas

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Making_of_a_Godol

Comment: @DoubleAA do you know why the question is on hold when you provided an excellent, source-based and not opinion-based answer?